# What is the PDF of the observation vector in the errors-in-variables model?

Tags: probability

Consider the linear relation $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{z}$.  The vector $\mathbf{x}$ is unknown, and a noisy version of the system matrix $\mathbf{H}$, i.e., $\tilde{\mathbf{H}} = \mathbf{H} + \mathbf{E}$ is known. The noise term $\mathbf{z}$ and the rows of $\mathbf{E}$ are i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2\mathbf{I})$. Given $\mathbf{y}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{H}}$, I am unable to characterize the distribution of $\mathbf{y}$.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Assume the vectors $\mathbf{y}$, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ are $N \times 1-$dimensional, while the matrix $\mathbf{H}$ is $N \times p$. By the way, this is the errors-in-variable model commonly used in system identification.

Comment: The distribution of $y_i=\sum_{j}H_{ij}x_j+z_i$ is normal with mean $\sum_{j}H_{ij}x_j$ and variance $\sigma^2$, according to your setup.

Comment: Hi Alex, but the point is we do not know $\mathbf{H}$.  We just have access to noisy version $\tilde{\mathbf{H}}$.

Comment: In that case you need to incorporate the distribution of $x$,which has both a mean and variance.